# Blade if(isset) is not working Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am trying to check the variable is already set or not using blade version. But the **raw php is working** but **the blade version is not**. Any help?

controller:

```
public function viewRegistrationForm()
{
    $usersType = UsersType::all();
    return View::make('search')->with('usersType',$usersType);
}
```

view:

```
{{ $usersType or '' }}
```

it shows the error :

**Undefined variable: usersType (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\clubhub\app\views\search.blade.php)**

Comment: How does that *raw php version* look like?

Comment: if (isset($usersType)){
    var_dump($usersType);
}

which is working. But i want to do it with blade .

Comment: What (exact) version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Hmm.. try to find the cached view file `app/storage/views`. If there are many files. Delete all and reload the browser so only the views rendered will be regenerated

Comment: delete all the record except .gitkeep. no luck.. also tried in chrome.

Comment: What do you mean no luck? Go through the view files that get generated and find the one with the `search` content. Then look what `{{ $usersType or '' }}` got compiled into.

Comment: it is showing <?php echo isset($usersType) ? $usersType : ''; ?> 

i think this is for echo.. but how can i remove this echo ? also tried {{{ }}}

Comment: Well this actually looks right. Are you sure the error is coming from this exactly line or do you have other usages of `$usersType` in the view?

Comment: I am sure this is the line and i have no other usage

Comment: {{ isset($usersType) ? $usersType : ' ' }} is working. bt when i try this it shows the error again: <div class="form-group"> <label for="">Choose Your Type</label> &nbsp; @foreach( $usersType as $type ) <input type="checkbox" class='default-checkbox'> <span>{{ $type->type }}</span> &nbsp; @endforeach </div>

---- at -> lukasgeiter

Comment: I knew it! You have another usage. the `@foreach()` uses `$usersType` so if it is undefined it will throw an error

Comment: If the line above does not trigger the given error, this question should be closed

Comment: `{{$userType ?? ''}}` is the best way with latest version

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`{{ $usersType or '' }}` is working fine. The problem here is your foreach loop:

```
@foreach( $usersType as $type )
    <input type="checkbox" class='default-checkbox'> <span>{{ $type->type }}</span> &nbsp; 
@endforeach
```

I suggest you put this in an `@if()`:

```
@if(isset($usersType))
    @foreach( $usersType as $type )
        <input type="checkbox" class='default-checkbox'> <span>{{ $type->type }}</span> &nbsp; 
    @endforeach
@endif
```

You can also use @forelse. Simple and easy.

```
@forelse ($users as $user)
   <li>{{ $user->name }}</li>
@empty
   <p>No users</p>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 25):

```
@isset($usersType)
  // $usersType is defined and is not null...
@endisset
```

For a detailed explanation refer [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#if-statements):

> In addition to the conditional directives already discussed, the `@isset` and `@empty` directives may be used as convenient shortcuts for their respective PHP functions

Comment: Please put a short explanation along with your code.

Answer (score 18):

Use ?? , 'or' not supported in updated version.

```
{{ $usersType or '' }}  ❎
{{ $usersType ?? '' }} ✅
```

Answer (score 6):

Use 3 curly braces if you want to echo

```
{{{ $usersType or '' }}}
```

Comment: tried .. but no luck. using raw php it is working. I also tried 

{{{ isset($usersType) ? $usersType or '' }}} and {{ isset($usersType) ? $usersType or '' }}

no improvement .. :(

Comment: Does this work? `{{{ isset($usersType) ? $usersType : '' }}}`

Comment: Then this means that your blade file is not properly parsed. Is it correctly named as `.blade.php`?

Comment: {{ isset($usersType) ? $usersType : ' ' }} is working. bt when i try this it shows the error again:

        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="">Choose Your Type</label>  &nbsp;
              @foreach( $usersType as $type )
          <input type="checkbox" class='default-checkbox'> <span>{{ $type->type }}</span> &nbsp;
            @endforeach
          </div>

Comment: Thanks mate, , ,  This is what exactly i was looking for.. :-)

Answer (score 6):

**On Controller**

```
$data = ModelName::select('name')->get()->toArray();
return view('viewtemplatename')->with('yourVariableName', $data);
```

**On Blade file**

```
@if(isset($yourVariableName))
//do you work here
@endif
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ternary operator easily:

```
{{ $usersType ? $usersType : '' }}
```

Comment: Format your code properly. This will increase your code readability.

Answer (score 2):

```
@forelse ($users as $user)
    <li>{{ $user->name }}</li>
@empty
    <p>No users</p>
@endforelse
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

Use `??` instead or `{{ $usersType ?? '' }}`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the `optional()` helper.  Using the example here it would be:

`{{ optional($usersType) }}`

A more complicated example would be if, like me, say you are trying to access a property of a null object (ie. `$users->type`) in a view that is using `old()` helper.

`value="{{ old('type', optional($users)->type }}"`

Important to note that the brackets go around the object variable and not the whole thing if trying to access a property of the object.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-optional