# converting BLOB to String Laravel 9.x

Tags: laravel

So i have a database with documents saved in it. The content is saved in BLOB type. Now i want to be able to edit it. For that, my programm uses an editor, which is imbedded in html. My idea was to decode the binary type BLOB to string and then insert it into the textarea from html via a blade template. Sending the data from php to html works, but there seems to be something wrong while converting. My testdocument has the content 'test' in it however, it shows 'AA==' when loading the page.
Here are my code snippets:

This is my database migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('documents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('id');
        $table->foreignId('owner_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('document_name');
        $table->string('release_state')->default('Privat');
        $table->integer('call')->default(0); //wird erzeugt und auf null gesetzt inkrement erfolgt woanders
        $table->binary('document_data'); //BLOB equivalent, hier ist der Content des Dokuments gespeichert
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

The data is originally saved here:

```
function save()
{
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['documentContent'])) {
        $documentContent = $_REQUEST['documentContent'];
    }
    else {

    }
    $id = Auth::id();

    $document = Documents::create([
        'owner_id' => $id,
        'document_name' => 'Placeholder will be replaced', //$daten->input('document_name'),
        'document_data' => $documentContent
    ]);
    return redirect('editor');
}
```

This is my function, where i get the id from the document and try to convert it

```
function document_edit(Request $daten)
    {

        $document_databinary = Documents::select('document_data')->where('id', $daten->input('id'))->get();
        $document_data = base64_encode(pack('H*', base_convert($document_databinary, 2, 16)));


        return view('editor', ['document_data' => $document_data]);
    }
```

This is where i want to put the data

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form method="POST" action="/editor/save">
    @csrf
    @isset($document_data)
    <textarea name="documentContent" id="documentContent" required>
    <p>{{$document_data}}</p>
    </textarea>
    @else
    <textarea name="documentContent" id="documentContent">
      <p></p>
    </textarea>

    @endif

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="save">Datei speichern</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I already checked the .bin file from the database, there is no problem in saving the data to it in the first place.
Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a BLOB field to store plain text?  How you decode it would depend entirely on how you encoded it first, and you haven't mentioned or shown us that code ....  FWIW you could simplify your code a bit using [Blade's `or` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497538/blade-ifisset-is-not-working-laravel) to get rid of the whole `isset() ... @endif` test. You'll still need a test for whether or not to include `required`, maybe using [Blade's attribute tricks](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#additional-attributes), eg `@required(isset($document_data))`.

Comment: BLOB is used, because the user should be able to insert images into the document aswell. I thought its the easiest to just store the whole thing in binary type then. I will add the encoding aswell shortly. I will edit the post, so you can see how i added the data.

Comment: How do you type/display an image in a `<textarea>`?  You may have your reasons and maybe this all makes sense for your requirements, but FWIW it seems to me you are making this harder than it needs to be, by using this very unusual approach.  If you want images in the DB, store them as BLOBs in their own column or table.  If you have text to store in a DB, store it as TEXT/VARCHAR/etc.

Comment: `base64_encode(pack('H*', base_convert(..., 2, 16)))` is going to be returning `AA==` always because you are passing a Collection to `base_convert`

Comment: @Don'tPanic i didnt think about that so far but i´ll try to further explain what i want to do in that section of my application. My user is able to create documents for later use. This document needs text and images, so he can customize it as he wants. If he wants to edit it later, he can do that by loading the document back into the editor. Thats what im trying to achieve here. 
My thought was, that its easier to store the whole document in BLOB type and convert it back, but yeah right now im noticing this wont work for images at all if im going down this approach.

Comment: @lagbox can you further explain that please? What Collection am i passing? Right now i think im just passing the value from document_data and thats binary

Comment: you are not ... `Documents::select('document_data')->where('id', $daten->input('id'))->get();` is returning a Collection of Document models which you have only selected the `document_data` field for .... this is not a single value